# Can't get the delegate of the gradle IncrementalProcessingEnvironment in STS 4

Tags: spring-tool-suite, lombok

Since I installed the Spring Tool Suite 4 I get on every class definition the warning

```
Can't get the delegate of the gradle IncrementalProcessingEnvironment.
```

I do not use gradle for building my project but maven. So, why is there a need for the gradle IncrementalProcessingEnvironment? How can I get rid of these warnings?

Comment: Did you upgrade existing STS3 to STS4 via an update site? Can you reproduce the problem with brand new blank workspace and a new Spring Boot project created via the Spring Starter wizard? If yes, please tell us you create the project. Which starters do you have on the project?

Comment: It is a fresh STS4, no upgrade. I removed all old eclipse settings from my project and used a new workspace. Then I imported my project as a maven project. One thing: I added the lombok agent to the STS start parameters. Maybe this has an impact.

Comment: would be good if you could attach or point to a sample project that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Create any new Spring Boot Initializer project with the web and lombok module. Then you would see the warning inside of STS on the line of the definition of the application class. Make sure that you have lombok enabled in your STS!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like this got reported here, too:
https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/95

And looks like this is related to Lombok being installed and used within Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse. Since Lombok is modifying the underlying Eclipse code quite a bit when installed, I wonder if Lombok is already compatible with Eclipse 4.9 (2018-09), which is used in the Spring Tools 4. It is not more than a wild guess, but I assume the problem is related to that.

It also looks like something like this already got reported to the Lombok project: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1813 - and people report that the Edge build of Lombok works better or even fixes the issue. Would recommend to give the Edge build of Lombok a try.

Comment: Indeed, using the edge build of lombok as javaagent for STS4 everything looks good. Tanks for checking!

Comment: Seems this issue has fixed in latest (1.18.8) lombok version

Answer (score 0):

try change sts path lombox version same to maven dependency lombox version

double click dependency lombox.jar select ide sts.exe (i did ok)